# Connecting to persistent volume in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I'm in the process of converting a stack to k8s. The database requires persistent storage.

I have used `kubectl create -f pv.yaml`

**pv.yaml *(with edits based on @whites11's answer)*:**

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/nfs"
  claimRef:
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    namespace: default
    name: mongo-persisted-storage
```

I then create an [example mongo replica set](https://github.com/cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar/blob/master/example/StatefulSet/mongo-statefulset.yaml).

When I look at my k8s dashboard I see the error:

> PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "mongo-persistent-storage-mongo-0"
>   (repeated 2 times)

[image]

In the persistent volume tab I see the volume which looks ok:

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring out the next step to make the volume claim happen successfully.

#### Edit #2

I went into the PVC page on the GUI and added a volume to the claim manually *(based on feedback from @whites11)*. I can see that the PVC has been updated with the volume but it is still pending.

[image]

#### Edit #3

Realizing that since making the change suggested by @whites11, the original error message in the pod has changed. It is now "persistentvolume "pvvolume" not found (repeated 2 times)", I think I just need to figure out where I wrote pvvolume, instead of pv-volume. (or it could be the `-` was auto-parsed out somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to manually bind your PV to your PVC, by adding the appropriate `claimRef` section to the PV spec.

In practice, edit your PV with the method you prefer, and add a section similar to this:

```
claimRef:
  name: mongo-persisted-storag
  namespace: <your PVC namespace>
```

Than, you need to edit your PVC to bind the correct volume, by adding the following in its `spec` section:

```
volumeName: "<your volume name>"
```

Here an explanation on how this process works: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/persistent_volumes.html#persistent-volumes-volumes-and-claim-prebinding

Comment: thank you, I'm assuming if I'm not using a namespace both PV and services will all be on the default one?

Comment: PV is not namespaced, service will be on default if you don't specify it

Comment: Sorry I'm still having trouble figuring this out. I updated my pv.yaml in my question based on your answer. Does it look right? I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Is the PVC still unclaimed?

Comment: Yes PVC shows as `pending` on one page and still this error on the StatefulSet `PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "mongo-persistent-storage-mongo-0" (repeated 2 times)`

Comment: Yeah sorry, try also adding volumeName in your PVC (answer updated)

Comment: no problem it is hard to diagnose without the system in front of you. I added another edit to my question.

Comment: I don't know why but there seemed to be a problem with having `-` in the name of my volume. I did the same thing but with `pvvolume` instead of `pv-volume` and I was able to get past the error. I have a new error now but it is out of scope for the question. Thank you.